# How do i make product image show in mobile version?

Tags: css, woocommerce, cart

I need some help please, i have a problem with my woocommerce site. 
On mobile version on the cart page the image of the product wont show , i know it from the theme but i dont know how to fix it. Any idea? Thanks

Comment: Please go read How to Ask. We expect you to ask specific questions here, about problems with code. Right now, you have more or less only described the situation to us. If you want to get help here - then you need to describe to us what you have already tried to solve the problem yourself.
¿Which code is not working? ¿When is working? ¿Any code you can share? ¿Have you tried contacting/asking the theme creator? It seems is a theme issue.

Comment: hi ,yea i know it a theme issue ,i've contacted the theme creator and they told me the only way it with custom code. i've tryed any php and css code i've find ,nothing work . I'm not a developer so i cant tell u exactly . The problem i got it a bit wierd. In the cart page my product image it not showing at all in mobile version . It working in the desktop or table version . so i guessed it from css